# How to rotate an object around a vector in POV-Ray?

Tags: rotation, geometry, povray

I find it surprisingly difficult to find the rotation that moves an object from one given point to another one in POV-Ray.

Geometrically it's simple enough to find: I calculate the distance `Dist` from the origin to the target point `PointT` (green), and create `Point0` at `<Dist, 0, 0>` (blue). Then I calculate from `Point0` and `PointT` the angle between them and the perpendicular to them. The rotation by `AngleD` around `Perp` moves `Point0` to `Point1` = `PointT`.

In POV-Ray I can use `vaxis_rotate` to calculate `Point1`. But I want to actually rotate an object (which, of course, will not be a sphere), and I don't see an obvious way to do this. I tried `rotate -AngleD*Perp`, but that gives a slightly different result (red).

How can I do to an object, what `vaxis_rotate` does to a point?

```
#declare PointT = <2, 2, 2>;

#declare Dist = VDist(<0, 0, 0>, PointT);
#declare Point0 = <Dist, 0, 0>;
#declare AngleD = VAngleD(PointT, Point0);
#declare Perp = VPerp_To_Plane(PointT, Point0);
#declare Point1 = vaxis_rotate(Point0, Perp, -AngleD);

sphere{Point0, R   pigment{color Blue}  }
sphere{Point1, R   pigment{color Green}  }

sphere{
    Point0, R
    rotate -AngleD*Perp
    pigment{color Red}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like the only way to directly specify rotations is with [Euler angles](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/49/). If needs be you could generate an [explicit rotation matrix](https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/Home/rotation-matrices-and-formulas/rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis-in-3-dimensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation matrix in the link provided by meowgoesthedog gives the expected result.

```
#macro RotMatFromVectorAndAngle(Vector, Angle)

    // takes normalized vector and angle in radians

    #local U = Vector.x;
    #local V = Vector.y;
    #local W = Vector.z;
    #local Sin = sin(Angle);
    #local Cos = cos(Angle);

    #local M11 = U*U + (1-U*U)*Cos;
    #local M12 = U*V*(1-Cos) - W*Sin;
    #local M13 = U*W*(1-Cos) + V*Sin;

    #local M21 = U*V*(1-Cos) + W*Sin;
    #local M22 = V*V + (1-V*V)*Cos;
    #local M23 = V*W*(1-Cos) - U*Sin;

    #local M31 = U*W*(1-Cos) - V*Sin;
    #local M32 = V*W*(1-Cos) + U*Sin;
    #local M33 = W*W + (1-W*W)*Cos;

    matrix <M11, M12, M13,
            M21, M22, M23,
            M31, M32, M33,
            0  , 0  , 0  >

#end
```

Applied to the sphere from the example above:

```
#declare Angle = VAngle(PointT, Point0);
#declare Perp = VPerp_To_Plane(PointT, Point0);
sphere{
    Point0, R
    RotMatFromVectorAndAngle(Perp, Angle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for Axis_Rotate_Trans in transforms.inc

```
#include "transforms.inc" 

sphere {
  ..., ...
  Axis_Rotate_Trans(
    VPerp_To_Plane(<...>, <...>), 
    VAngleD(<...>, <...>)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for short, let be a unit vector, and suppose you want a rotation about it by alpha degrees. Then v1 v2 v3 *alpha WILL NOT yield the desired transformation. It is a bug, a serious one.